# GRASS : r.resamp.rst error : "Not enough disk space--cannot write files"‏

Tags: grass-gis

When I try to use the tool "r.resamp.rst", it gives me as answer:

```
*r.resamp.rst input=map@PERMANENT ew_res=11 ns_res=11 pcurv=curv           
Processing all selected output files will require
261320 bytes of disk space for temp files.
Temporarily changing the region to desired resolution ...
Changing back to the original region ...
Percent complete:
Not enough disk space--cannot write files
Not enough disk space--cannot write files
Not enough disk space--cannot write files
Not enough disk space--cannot write files
.....
interpolate() failed
dnorm in mainc after grid before out1= 12.961481
ERROR: split_and_interpolate() failed*
```

I have 14GB left on my hard disk so I don't understand why they are saying me that.

I tried to find solution, and I found some answers (e.g. here : http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/2005-April/018152.html)
but I don't understand.

They speak about a "ulimit -f" function, but where should I write it ?

It doesn't work in GRASS.
I am on Windows, so maybe that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in the GRASS Users mailing list:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2013-March/thread.html#67370

(I wonder how to deal with the crossposting between project mailing lists and gis stackexchange.com...)

Comment: i would not mind if answer would be here too. i dont official stance

Comment: While it has been discussed, I am not sure that the problem has been resolved in that thread. I would always suggest that you proved at-least a summery of the solution and a link to the thread.

Comment: The link is there :) The solution appears to be that the user wanted a different functionality...